# C# Linq Where Date Between 2 Dates if date stored in database in string format

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get data using c# linq between two dates but the date stored in the database is in string format.

```
DateTime dFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("01-04-2019", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime dTo = DateTime.ParseExact("02-04-2019", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  

 var List = (from Receipt in DB.tbl_PurchaseReceipts 
             where DateTime.ParseExact(Receipt.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= dFrom && DateTime.ParseExact(Receipt.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= dTo
             select Receipt).ToList();
```

Getting Error:

> Method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String,
>   System.IFormatProvider)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: The best solution, by a considerable margin, is **not to store dates in the database as a string**. Is it an option to fix that bug, and instead store them as dates? Any other solution will be more complicated, **massively** slower, and take more storage space.

Comment: It also means you can't take advantage of indexing or [Sargable queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean).

Comment: that's because the above `LINQ` gets translated to a `SQL` query and `DateTime.ParseExact()` is part of C#, it doesn't mean anything in `SQL` try taking out the method call and directly provide the value in `LINQ`, ideally you should store DateTime in DB.

Comment: Is there any solution, except to store DateTime in DB?

Comment: Are you using EF, if so, what version, or LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @NetMage I am not using EF. I am using LINQ in c#.

Comment: `DB.tbl_PurchaseReceipts` implies you are using LINQ to SQL or EF. LINQ comes in different flavors and they support different capabilities. For example, if you were using LINQ to Objects you would never get that error message, only LINQ to SQL or EF provides that error message. So again, are you using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to EF, and if EF, what version?

Comment: `Is there any solution` Yes. You could `ToList` the `tbl_PurchaseReceipts` to pull down the entire data to the client and do the filtering there. This is **not** a good idea.

Comment: Thank you very much you guys gave me great ideas & suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to parse out the parts manually and build a new `DateTime`:

```
var List = (from Receipt in DB.tbl_PurchaseReceipts 
            let rDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(Receipt.Date.Substring(6,4)),Convert.ToInt32(Receipt.Date.Substring(0,2)),Convert.ToInt32(Receipt.Date.Substring(3,2)))
            where dFrom <= rDate && rDate <= dTo
            select Receipt)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this code working for the date format MM-dd-yyyy

Comment: You can change the `Substring` values to work with other formats, as long as they are consistent, e.g. just swap the last two parameters to the `DateTime` constructor to work with `dd-MM-yyyy`.